# FormArray getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormArray where I am passing an IsEditMode:boolean flag to toggle the view from Edit Mode to Read-Only mode.

When I change the value of IsEditMode, I am getting error

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'

I tried looking for an example but was not able to find anything. Please suggest if there is a better way to do this as well.

```
createForm(): void {
    this.itemForm = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  createItem(jp: Item & EditMode): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: jp.id,
      profileId: jp.profileId,
      name: [jp.name, Validators.required],
      isEditMode: [jp.isEditMode]
    });
  }

addNewItem() {
    this.items = this.jobPreferenceForm.get(
      'items'
    ) as FormArray;
    this.items.push(
      this.crateItem({
        id: 0,
        profileId: '',
        name: '',
        isEditMode: true
      })
    );
  }

<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
            <tbody>
              <tr formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of itemForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
                <td>
                  <span *ngIf="!item.value.isEditMode">{{item.value.name}}</span>
                  <div *ngIf="item.value.isEditMode" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a *ngIf="!item.value.isEditMode" (click)="item.value.isEditMode = !item.value.isEditMode">Edit</a>
                  <a *ngIf="item.value.isEditMode" class="text-muted mr-2" [attr.disabled]="!item.valid" (click)="cancel(item)">Cancel</a>
                  <a *ngIf="item.value.isEditMode" class="text-success mr-2" (click)="save(item)">Save</a>
                  <a *ngIf="item.value.isEditMode" class="text-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: We would be able to help you better if we could see the way your code is actually included in your project. Could you separate out the code snippets above and label which angular lifecycle hooks you are using to render this component? This error is thrown in development environments to let you know that a value you are updating in your component is not being rendered on your front-end view. This usually occurs when you have updated a value outside of the angular lifecycle hooks in the correct way.